# Protractor ignoresynchronization not working properly

Tags: javascript, automation, protractor

Kindly suggest me a solution, I am developing the e2e test suite for one of my angular applications,in which i am using **browser.ignoreSynchronization = true** to disable synchronization  and then, when i enable synchronization  by using **browser.ignoreSynchronization = false** my script unable to click element . On the other hand when i use **waitForAngularEnabled** it work .

Comment: Please go through this link once: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1):

that is because there is no such option anymore https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/lib/config.ts

In fact, `waitForAngularEnabled` was developed to substitute `ignoreSynchronization`, so you should only stick to the use of that command